Jon Stewart Interview with psychologist
There was a Jon Stewart interview within the last year where the psychologist said that if you put a bunch of politically right leaning people in a room together they will come out even further to the right.
And the same with left-leaning as well.
I want to refer to that interview in terms of people only reading the news they want to read these days.
What interview was that?

It was actually this year.
It's professor Cass Sunstein on the Daily Show talking about his book Wiser.
